# How can I make temporary arrays for several threads without constantly allocating and deallocating?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have one function that I'm attempting to parallelize with OpenMP.  I has a big `for` loop where every iteration is independent of the others, and I'd like to use something like

```
#pragma omp for private(j)
```

to parallelize the loop.

One problem is that each iteration of the loop requires a substantial amount of temporary workspace, enough that I think it will likely kill performance if I allocate and deallocate this temporary workspace with once per iteration. My environment has "workspace" objects in it, and there are no problem associated with reusing an old workspace object as-is.

How can I allocate workspace for each thread before the threads are made (and I don't know how many of them there are)? How can I tell each thread to pick a unique workspace object from the pool?

Comment: rather than deallocating workspaces, shove them into a queue (stack, or any other controllable sequence) and pull them from that on the preamble to your loop. The 'pop()' from said sequence can initialize state as needed before returning the request. Furthermore, you can tailor access to the sequence-pool to do the actual *allocation* of initial workspace content for you. You preamble to entering the loops then just becomes a "gimme" request to the workspace allocator backed by the sequence. (hope that made sense).

Comment: @WhozCraig: It's not really clear to me; maybe you could write up an answer and provide more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `omp_get_max_threads()` and allocate enough workspaces for all threads (e.g., an array of workspaces with `omp_get_max_threads()` elements.), and then on each thread use `omp_get_thread_num()` to know which thread is running on so it can get its own workspace.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing the point, but wouldn't the following strategy work for you?

```
void foo() {

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    // allocate work-space here, so to make it private to the thread
    thread_workspace t;

    #pragma omp for
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      // Each thread has its local work-space allocated outside the for loop
    }
  } // End of the parallel region

}
```

Comment: It would work, but the thread_workspace is pretty huge, and since `foo()` is called very frequently (`main()` is basically a bunch of nested loops with `foo()` in the middle of it) I want to save the workspaces between calls to `foo()`, making it into `void foo(workspace_blob,other_stuff)`, with `workspace_blob` declared and initialized in `main()`.

Comment: Is it too much work to use orphaned directives inside `foo()` and declare the parallel region in `main()`?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the Object Pool design pattern.  [Here's](http://www.oodesign.com/object-pool-pattern.html) a description.  You would obviously need to make the acquire and release methods for the workspaces thread safe (3 methods in the ReusablePool need synchronization).  The number of workspaces would grow to the total number needed at any one time.  Reclaimed workspaces would be reused by the ReusablePool.

> Although the object pool is handling the object instantiation it's
>   main purpose is to provide a way for the clients to reuse the objects
>   like they are new objects.